# Problemas ao conectar aplicação do Intel XDK ao banco de dados

Tags: php, javascript, intel-xdk, wamp

Boa tarde. Estou com o seguinte problema: Criei uma aplicação no intel xdk porém não consigo de forma alguma enviar os dados de cadastro de usuário ao banco de dados. Estou utilizando o wampserver. Olhei um tutorial na internet e no tutorial o cara utilizou as mesmas ferramentas que eu, porém o meu simplesmente não da certo. Não tenho muito conhecimento em php, copiei a classe do tutorial e a modelei conforme a minha aplicação, peguei também a classe app.js e fiz a mesma coisa. Há algo de errado nelas?

classe php:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: Application/html; charset-UTF-8");

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$nickname = $_POST['nickname'];
$curso = $_POST['curso'];
$semestre = $_POST['semestre'];
$ra = $_POST['ra'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];


$db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","aluno");

$sql = "insert into aluno values(NULL,'".$nome."', '".$nickname."', '".$curso."', '".$semestre."', '".$ra."', '".$email."', '".$senha."')";

$db->query($sql);
$db->close;

?>
```

Javascript

```
(function(){


"use strict";

function event_handlers(){

  $(document).on("click", "#envia", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

          var recupera =  $("form#cadastro").serialize();
          var recupera = "http://localhost/app/apicadastro.php"
              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: url,
                  data: recupera,
                  async: false

              }).done(function(){

                 navigator.notification.alert("Dados inseridos com sucesso", null, "Sucesso", "OK");

              }).fail(function(){

                navigator.notification.alert("Falha!", null, "Falha", "OK");

              });


  });


}

document.addEventListener("app.Ready", event_handlers, false);


})();
```

Comment: Viva. Estás a reescrever a variável `recupera` com o URL, e assim falta-te a definição da variável URL.

Comment: Oi foxtrot, fiz a correção, obrigado. Porém mesmo assim os dados não são inseridos, tem algo de errado com o php?

Comment: @RomuloFilho ainda não está corrigido aqui na pergunta, corrige `var recupera = $("form#cadastro").serialize();` está sendo sobrescrita logo em seguida em `var recupera = "http://localhost/app/apicadastro.php"`